# Swift - Programmatically adding a UIView is causing it to be immediately removed from its parent view

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiview

**EDIT - Added GitHub link to relevant source code:** https://github.com/stumpy3toes/UIView-Issue

So i'm experiencing a really strange issue with a set of custom popup classes. Essentially the idea is I create 2 UIViews, one is the mask to darken or blur the background and added on top of that is the popup to be displayed. So I add the popup as a subview to the mask and then add the mask as a subview to the presenting view controller's view.

The problem is when using my popup controller class to handle presentation and dismissal of the 2 views i've noticed that the mask view is being immediately removed from the presenting view controller straight after the presenting animation is complete. I do not believe this has anything to with my coding and happens automatically.

Here is the following relevant classes to give more context to the issue:

UIPopup

```
class UIPopup {
let contentView: UIView

init() {
    self.contentView = UIView()
    self.contentView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
}

func addToParent(parentView: UIView) {
    //remove()
    parentView.addSubview(contentView)
    parentView.bringSubviewToFront(contentView)
    addConstraints(parentView)
}

func remove() {
    if contentView.superview != nil {
        contentView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}

func addConstraints(superview: UIView) {}
func prepareForShow() {}
func animateShow() {}
func animateDismiss() {}
}
```

UIPopupMask

```
class UIPopupMask: UIPopup {
private let defaultColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0)
private let defaultAlpha: CGFloat = 0.7

override init() {
    super.init()
    contentView.backgroundColor = defaultColor.colorWithAlphaComponent(defaultAlpha)
}

override func addConstraints(superview: UIView) {
    superview.addConstraints([
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: superview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: superview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: superview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: superview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    ])
}

override func prepareForShow() {
    contentView.backgroundColor = defaultColor.colorWithAlphaComponent(0)
}

override func animateShow() {
    contentView.backgroundColor = defaultColor.colorWithAlphaComponent(defaultAlpha)
}

override func animateDismiss() {
    contentView.backgroundColor = defaultColor.colorWithAlphaComponent(0)
}
}
```

UIPopupController

```
class UIPopupController {
private let mask: UIPopup
private let popup: UIPopup

private let animationDuration: Double = 0.3

init(popup: UIIndicatorView, presentingViewController: UIView) {
    self.mask = UIPopupMask()
    self.popup = UIIndicatorView()
    self.popup.addToParent(self.mask.contentView)
}

func show(presentingViewController: UIView, animated: Bool, completion: Void -> Void) {
    setup(presentingViewController)

    mask.prepareForShow()
    popup.prepareForShow()

    UIView.animateWithDuration(animated ? animationDuration : 0.0, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.mask.animateShow()
        self.popup.animateShow()
    }) { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
        completion()
    }
}

func dismiss(animated: Bool, completion: Void -> Void) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(animated ? animationDuration : 0.0, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.mask.animateDismiss()
        self.popup.animateDismiss()
    }) { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
        self.mask.contentView.hidden = true
        completion()
    }
}

private func setup(presentingViewController: UIViewController) {
    if let sView = mask.contentView.superview where sView != presentingViewController.view {
        remove()
    }
    if mask.contentView.superview == nil {
        mask.addToParent(presentingViewController.view)
    }
    mask.contentView.hidden = false
    presentingViewController.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}

private func remove() {
    mask.remove()
}
}
```

UIIndicatorView is simply a UIPopup that is a white rectangle with rounded corners.

The code I'm using to present the popup is just a UICollectionViewController (I have tried a UIViewController but to no avail):

```
let test = UIIndicator(presentingViewController: self.collectionView!)
test.show(self.collectionView!, animated: true, completion: {
})
```

And UIIndicator is currently a very simple subclass of UIPopupController:

```
class UIIndicator: UIPopupController {
init(presentingViewController: UIView) {
    super.init(popup: UIIndicatorView(), presentingViewController: presentingViewController)
}
}
```

However one way to bypass this issue, which I don't find to be a particularly viable solution for me, is to use local variables in the function 'show' in UIPopupController for the mask and popup; which for some reason this change means that they stay added and visible in the presenting view controller. Here's the code:

```
func show(presentingViewController: UIView, animated: Bool, completion: Void -> Void) {
    let popup2 = UIIndicatorView()
    let mask2 = UIPopupMask()
    popup2.addToParent(mask2.contentView)
    mask2.addToParent(presentingViewController)
    mask2.prepareForShow()
    popup2.prepareForShow()
    UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, animations: { () -> Void in
        mask2.animateShow()
        popup2.animateShow()
    }, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> Void in

    })
}
```

I've tried re-adding the mask view straight after it is removed and the presenting view controller view will claim that it is in its subviews but I cannot see it, so i'm guessing it isn't really there.

I've tried changing the properties of the mask and popup objects in the UIPopupController to 'var' and 'public', again this doesn't work.

I also noticed if I create local variables like I have in the kind of 'solution' above but then assign the values of the UIPopupController's mask and popup variables to those local variables like this:

```
let popup2 = UIIndicatorView()
let mask2 = UIPopupMask()
mask = mask2
popup = popup2
```

and then proceed to add and display the locally created variables on the presenting view controller then I experience the same issue of the mask being immediately removed.

I really don't understand whats going on here. It seems really buggy and part of me thinks that this maybe to do with a potential bug in Xcode as Swift is fairly new but thats a result of me just really not understanding this. I can imagine it maybe something trivially that i'm missing? Like a mistake in my coding but theres not much coding to it and I can't see one.

Sorry this is a long question but I thought it would be better to be thorough to make it easier for anyway to suggest a potential solution to this problem.

Comment: When you say immediately removed, do you mean displayed for some time and then removed or not displayed at all?

Comment: @Pranav It will display during the animation. So I did a test where they both faded in over 2 seconds and during that 2 seconds I could see them fading in but as soon as the animation finishes they both disappear.

Comment: Can you post your project on GitHub?

Comment: @Bannings I can do, although i've never posted something on GitHub and I'd rather only post just the relevant bits on there as I wouldn't be too keen on the idea of posting up the whole project. So it wouldn't be much more code than i've put above. I'll look into now though